# how to add textfield in iOS interactive notification

Tags: ios, ios8, notifications, ios9, uilocalnotification

I want to develop interactive notification just like imessage . i read documentation and i tried with adding multiple UIMutableUserNotificationAction to UIMutableUserNotificationCategory and display it. i want to display textfield just like iMessage . this is my problem

```
UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *notificationCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
notificationCategory.identifier = @"Email";
[notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1,notificationAction2,notificationAction3] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];
[notificationCategory setActions:@[notificationAction1,notificationAction2] forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextMinimal];
```

please help

Comment: Duplicate question and answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841227/adding-text-field-in-remote-notificaton-ios-8

Comment: thanks @Flipper. worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

```
let replyAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
replyAction.identifier = "REPLY_ACTION"
replyAction.title = "Reply"
replyAction.activationMode = UIUserNotificationActivationMode.Background
replyAction.authenticationRequired = false    
replyAction.destructive = false
//Set behaviour to .TextInput    
replyAction.behavior = .TextInput
```