# How can we add textfield to push notification in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift

I want to add textfield to push notification i.e when app in back ground.I add couple of code to UIUserNotificatioSetting.But I am not getting texfield to push notification,Any one can solve this Problem?

Answer (score 0):

Check this post it will be useful for you 
[Adding text field in Remote Notificaton, iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841227/adding-text-field-in-remote-notificaton-ios-8)

```
//creating the inline reply notification action
   let replyAction = UIMutableUserNotificationAction()
   replyAction.title = "Say Something"
   replyAction.identifier = "inline-reply"
   replyAction.activationMode = .Background
   replyAction.authenticationRequired = false
   replyAction.behavior = .TextInput

 //creating a category
   let notificationCategory:UIMutableUserNotificationCategory = UIMutableUserNotificationCategory()
   notificationCategory.identifier = "INVITE_CATEGORY"
   notificationCategory .setActions([replyAction], forContext: UIUserNotificationActionContext.Default)

 //registerting for the notification.
      application.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes:[ UIUserNotificationType.Sound, UIUserNotificationType.Alert,
            UIUserNotificationType.Badge], categories: NSSet(array:[notificationCategory]) as? Set<UIUserNotificationCategory>))
```