# Swift: Write in textfield when clicking on push notification action button and handle it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, unusernotificationcenter

I'm using `Xcode 9.4.1 (9F2000)` and `Swift`.

I have this code in `AppDelegate`:

```
func showPushButtons(){
    let replyAction = UNNotificationAction(
        identifier: "reply.action",
        title: "Reply to this message",
        options: [])

    let pushNotificationButtons = UNNotificationCategory(
        identifier: "allreply.action",
        actions: [replyAction],
        intentIdentifiers: [],
        options: [])

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([pushNotificationButtons])
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    let action = response.actionIdentifier
    let request = response.notification.request
    let content = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if action == "reply.action"{
        print("Reply button clicked")

        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

This makes the following:

When receiving a push notification, an action button will be visible called `Reply to this message`.

Currently, when clicking on the button, console prints `Reply button clicked`.

What I want to do:

If I click on the button a textfield and the keyboard should appear (as known from messaging apps). After writing some text and submitting/sending I want to receive this message in `AppDelegate` to handle it.

Do you have any idea how to do this? Any hint?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding text field in Remote Notification, iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841227/adding-text-field-in-remote-notification-ios-8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works now:

```
func showPushButtons(){
    let replyAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(
        identifier: "reply.action",
        title: "Reply on message",
        textInputButtonTitle: "Send",
        textInputPlaceholder: "Input text here")

    let pushNotificationButtons = UNNotificationCategory(
        identifier: "allreply.action",
        actions: [replyAction],
        intentIdentifiers: [],
        options: [])

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([pushNotificationButtons])
}
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    if  response.actionIdentifier  ==  "reply.action" {
        if let textResponse =  response as? UNTextInputNotificationResponse {
            let sendText =  textResponse.userText
            print("Received text message: \(sendText)")
        }
    }
    completionHandler()
}
```

What it does: If you're receiving a push notification with `"category":"allreply.action"` and you make a force touch click on it, a textfield and the keyboard will appear and you can you can print it with `print("Received text message: \(sendText)")`.

Don't forget to call `showPushButtons()` from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and prepare the app for receiving (remote) push notifications.

Comment: Any idea why above code is not working in iOS 13 ? Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your `replyAction` with this one:

```
let replyAction = UNTextInputNotificationAction(identifier: "reply.action", title: "message", options: [], textInputButtonTitle: "Send", textInputPlaceholder: "type something …")
```

This should resolve your problem.